# Is there a way to automatically generate the folder structure and function.json files for compiled Azure Functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

If I use Visual Studio ([2017 15.3 preview with Azure Functions Tools for Visual Studio installed](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/05/10/azure-function-tools-for-visual-studio-2017/)) to publish the following function to Azure, it will automatically generate the `function.json` file and place it in a folder that represents the function's name. I'm assuming it does this by examining the attributes on the method and parameters.

```
[FunctionName("EmailNotifications")]
public static async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger(Topics.Enquiries, "EmailNotifications", AccessRights.Listen, Connection = "MyConnectionString")] Enquiry enquiry, TraceWriter log)
{

}
```

I'd like to generate these files myself, at build time, so that they can be packaged up for deployment via our regular deployment pipeline. Is there a way to do this?

I'm hoping that whatever Visual Studio uses under the hood as part of the publish process is exposed somewhere, but I'm having trouble finding this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's correct, there's a post-build tool that examines the attributes and generates function.json; but it's problematic. 
The current path should be generating them already at build-time, so you can include them in deployment. Search your project's output directory for function.json.
Is that not happening for you?

FWIW, We're actually hoping to remove the need to generate function.json from attributes  (see https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/1508 ) and have Functions just directly load the dll and consume the attributes directly.

Note that you don't need the Azure Functions Tools installed on your build machine. The function.json files are generated from the NuGet package [Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions). As long as you have a Visual Studio 2017 msbuild on your build machine, a regular build will produce the right files. If using VSTS, use the VS 2017 build agent. See [Deploying Visual Studio 2017 Function Projects with VSTS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/06/01/deploying-visual-studio-2017-function-projects-with-vsts/) for more information.

Comment: Man do I feel dumb- it *was* in the build output. I don't know how I missed it! Removing the need for `function.json` altogether would be a great step in reducing the amount of ceremony needed to get these things running.

Comment: @ChrisPayne - can you elaborate on that last sentence. If there's a post-build step that automatically generates the correct function.json for you, does that give you an optimal solution for your scenario?

Comment: Yes, I have the build and deploy working end-to-end now, thanks. To be clearer, I meant that it'd be nice to not worry about folder structure / `function.json` files if all the information could be discovered by scanning the dlls, which is what the work item you linked to was discussing.

Comment: @ChrisPayne Note that the function.json files are generated from the NuGet package [Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions/1.0.0-alpha6). As long as you have a VS 2017 version of msbuild on your build machine, a regular build will produce the right files. In other words, you don't need the Azure Functions Tools installed on your build machine.

Comment: I'd noticed that I could build this project in a version of VS that didn't have the Azure Functions Tools installed, so had guessed that one of the nuget packages was responsible for this. Good to know which one though!